# Simple Windows server user migration

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

I'm setting up a shiny new Windows Server 2008 R2 standard and want to copy my users from a Windows SBS 2003 to the new server.

Is there a smart and easy way to do that without doing all that mambo jambo "Migrating Domain Controllers" stuff?

Because it will not be an AD controller, no DNS server, no DHCP server, etc. Just plain file sharing services.

Comment: You're talking about migrating accounts from a domain controller (for that is what your SBS server will be) to a non-DC? Not much simple about that, sorry.#

Comment: are you planning on decommissioning the SBS server?

Comment: Yes, I'm taking over a badly planed, and driven, windows network. So now I'm consolidating a some win servers into a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. No.

No easy way to do it, sorry.

Comment: So there is no simple way to export-import users and password?

Comment: The simple way IS to use that "mambo jambo migrating domain controllers" stuff. Both myself, Tomtom and anyone with a passing familiarity with Windows servers would have completed migrating the accounts that way in half of the time since you asked this question.

Comment: Passwords, no way. But you could use a script to export all the users and then another one to import them all. But they would all have new passwords.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all answers. Yes, I figured out that I have to go the powerScript path, that's ok.